# keep alive fragments of same navigation activity but sharing data

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, uinavigationcontroller

I am making this question because I have not found any good example in Java. There are 5 fragments for the bottom navigation bar: Home, Favorite, Upload, Inbox and User. Every time you switch fragments, the fragment is created again, exactly what I am not looking for. It is not only about replacing fragments, because Home and Favorite depend of each other: if you mark a product as favorite in the market, it must appear in favorite and same way around.

Here Navigation Activity

```
public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(UnipopApp.LoggedUser.getUserLogged() != null) setContentView(R.layout.main);
        else setContentView(R.layout.main_guest);
        setUpNavigation();
    }

    public void setUpNavigation() {
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
        NavHostFragment navHostFragment;
        if(UnipopApp.LoggedUser.getUserLogged() != null) {
            bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
            navHostFragment =
                (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        }
        else {
            bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_guest);
            navHostFragment =
                (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_guest);
        }

        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView,
            navHostFragment.getNavController());
    }
}
```

I would like something **scalable** and better if it is accompanied with examples. Thanks

Comment: EventBus could be of help in this scenario - https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Answer (score 0):

you need to store the item check=true or false in a list then you can read that list any where in your app.
or you can create a separate favorite items list and display the items in favorite section only. if user unselect the item from home then you can remove the item from favorite item list.
And if you are using mvvm then you can share one viewmodel between all fragments.